# Filter elastic data on array count

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

How can we fetch candidates which have at least one phone number from the below index data along with other conditions like must and should?

Using elastic version 6.*

```
        {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "docs",
            "_id": "1271",
            "_score": 1.518617,
            "_source": {
                "record": {
                    "createdDate": "2020-10-16T10:49:51.53",
                    "phoneNumbers": [
                        {
                            "type": "Cell",
                            "id": 0,
                            "countryCode": "+1",
                            "phoneNumber": "7845200448",
                            "extension": "",
                            "typeId": 700
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "entityType": "Candidate",                   
                "dbId": "1271",
                "id": "1271"
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by at least one phone number?

Comment: phonenumbers is an array type,so need candidates which have atleast one phone number in that array. array.length > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` query for this purpose like below which is a lightweight query in comparison with scripts:

```
{
  "query": {
      "exists": {
        "field": "record.phoneNumbers.phoneNumber"
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: let me check it again!

Comment: I just need check phonenumbers.count > 0

Comment: I edited my query. This query returns documents that have at least one phone number.

Answer (score 3):

> You can use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) that returns documents that contain one
> or more exact terms in a provided field.

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "record.phoneNumbers.phoneNumber.keyword": [
              "7845200448"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64388591",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "record": {
            "createdDate": "2020-10-16T10:49:51.53",
            "phoneNumbers": [
              {
                "type": "Cell",
                "id": 0,
                "countryCode": "+1",
                "phoneNumber": "7845200448",
                "extension": "",
                "typeId": 700
              }
            ]
          },
          "entityType": "Candidate",
          "dbId": "1271",
          "id": "1271"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1: For version 7.***

You need to use a [script query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html), to filter documents based on the provided script.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc['record.phoneNumbers.phoneNumber.keyword'].length > 0",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**For version 6.***

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": {
            "source": "doc['record.phoneNumbers.phoneNumber.keyword'].values.length > 0",
            "lang": "painless"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Ramakrishna Reddy please go through my updated answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: @Ramakrishna Reddy I tried the above script queries locally also, and they are working fine.

Comment: yeah it working my bad, thank u. you are saviour :)